# Detect real numbers beyond whole numbers

Tags: c++

This code is meant to detect REAL numbers from a string entered continuously by a user, and return the found real number as a double value .  I was able to construct it to the point where it detects whole numbers, but if I try a decimal number it doesn't detect it.  I think my error is within my isvalidReal() function, but I'm not sure how to move things around to get it to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double getaReal();  //function prototype
int value;

cout << "Enter a number: ";
value = getaReal();
cout << "the number entered is a real number: " <<value << endl;

return 0;
}





bool isvalidReal(string str)         //function to find real numbers.
{
int start = 0;
int i;
bool valid = true;
bool sign = false;

if (int(str.length()) == 0) valid = false;          //check for empty string
if (str.at(0) == '-' || str.at(0) == '+')            //check for sign
{
    sign = true;
    start = 1;                                   //check for real num at     position 1
}
if (sign && int(str.length()) == 1) valid = false;  //make sure there's atleast 1 char after the sign

i = start;
while (valid && i<int(str.length()))
{
    if (!isdigit(str.at(i))) valid = false;  //found a non-digit character
    i++;                                  // move to next character
}
return valid;
}





double getaReal()
{
bool isvalidReal(string);  //function declaration prototype
bool isnotreal = true;
string input;

while (isnotreal)
{
    try
    {
        cin >> input;     //accepts user input
        if (!isvalidReal(input)) throw input;
    }
    catch (string e)
    {
        cout << "No real number has been detected, continue to\n enter string values: ";
        continue;          //continues user input
    }
    isnotreal = false;
}
return atof(input.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Consider the fact that the character '.' is not a digit.

Comment: @JGroven I zeroed in on that bit of code as well.  I'm flipping through my text trying to figure out how to change that bit so that my function keeps real numbers and tosses away anything else.  I'm stuck though.